# If Error+ If + VlookUp

Tags: excel, if-statement, match, vlookup, nested-if

So I have list of hundreads of datas based on baseball positions.

There are three positions I am looking for, `1B`, `2B`, `3B`, `SS`. 
Let's say `A1-A10` I have positions. `C1-C4` a table showing only those positions.

The criteria is If `A1` is either, `1B`,`2B`,`3B`,`SS` give me `1`, if not `0`, and alongside I need to use if error.

I have this so far but it isn't working: `=IFERROR(IF(A1,C1:C4,1,FALSE),1),0)`. Could you guys help me please.

Thanks

Comment: I figured out the vlook up part: =VLOOKUP(A1,$C$1:$C$14,1,FALSE) so in instance if it's 1b in column A, it returns 1B in column B too. However; how do i get it to say "1" if its the same and "0", if its different. In instance i need to add an If statement

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to make a column with '1' or '0' in it based on whether or not one of those positions then see if this works for you.

=IF(OR(A1="1B",A1="2B",A1="3B",A1="SS"),1,0)

Comment: Thanks, that works ! However is there a simpler way to do this? meaning instead of doing 4 times A1="1B"... Could we use vlookup instead?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to lookup that you want to use VLOOKUP?

Comment: You could also use 'COUNTIF' and then you wouldn't need the nested 'OR' condition .... =COUNTIF(A1,$C$1:$C$4) ... as long as you only have a single cell in the first position you will always only result in a 1 or a 0